# Question about using Anonymous List Types

Tags: asp.net, generics, generic-list

```
private List<T> GetFieldList()
{
    var Fields = new { DisplayName = "MCP", FieldName = "t.MCP", FieldType = 1 };
    var FieldList = (new[] { Fields }).ToList();

    return FieldList;
}
```

Should I be able to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your tag "asp.net" this construction will be used as part of data binding.
Just use non generic :

```
private IList GetFieldList()
{
    var Fields = new { DisplayName = "MCP", FieldName = "t.MCP", FieldType = 1 };
    IList FieldList = (new[] { Fields }).ToList();

    return FieldList;
}
```

It would be nice handled by all data-bound controls.

Comment: This seems to work until I try to query against it using LINQ. I get an error "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collection.IList'. 'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'l'.

var list = GetFieldList();
var item = (from l in list where l.DisplayName = ddlFields.SelectedValue select l).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: @Jhorra, the cast not to IList, but IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

I just realized I don't need to use an anonymous list as I know the structure of the data I'm expecting, so I'll just create a small class for it.